# Unable to understand relative path in Groovy.bat -cp command

Tags: groovy

The following that I have to use to run my groovy class file

> ..\bin\groovy.bat  -cp ....;%classpath%;..\lib; GetTemplateNode.groovy

I am confused with .... part in the command before the groovy.bat and after the -cp.

Can you please explain me what each part of this command actually stand for?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `....` is probably a mistake. Other than that, the command is starting the GetTemplateNode.groovy script, and adds the `lib` folder, that is located one folder above, to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling to understand it !! The ... as you said is optional.